# Removing box after a div with border-radius is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, border-layout

I have a div with a span element in it, which will have a redirection function for it. The div has a border-radius property. All the working and UI is all looking fine. But when the element is selected am seeing a border box around the div.

Since it appears only for a minute time before redirection, I was unable to track what could be the CSS issue with it.

Here is my code:

HTML:
     
    Button Text

CSS:

```
.menu-button{
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px 5px 2%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

this is how the div on select looking like, before it moves to different page:

[image: button while selected]

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add `outline: none` in styles.

Comment: Don't forget to set an answer to correct for referencing material! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the `outline` of the *menu-button* class to `none`. Namely, `outline: none;`.

This is happening due to some default values of the `button` element. On Google Chrome, for example, the `outline` is a standard blue border to highlight where you are currently at.

Hence, by setting `outline: none;` will remove any `border` when you click on a `button` element.

---

This applies to `input` elements as well, for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Set outline attribute for the menu-button. like this

```
.menu-button{
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px 5px 2%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.menu-button{
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px 5px 2%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border:none;
}
```